# Azure web app connection issue from a different region

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I have got the setup shown in the diagram below, however I recently built a new web application within the UK south region but could not get it to connect to a SQL database in a different region on a different vnet but peered to the UK south vnet

The connection works if the database connectivity is made public, i.e no firewall rules, and no private vnet/endpoint integration, however if the database is then placed in a private endpoint on a vnet I cannot connect the app which runs in a different Azure region, i.e
If the web app is within the new app vnet, there is no connectivity and fails.

A user connecting via the VPN cannot get to the SQL database in the UK south region even though the VNETS are peered (main vnet and the new app vnet). I introduced global vNet peering.

I am unsure as to what I am missing here; any thoughts would be appreciated.

NB: What works is if I place the new app in the North EU region and in the App subnet which is also in the same region.

[image]